# What expect from Twitter leads submit_url?

Tags: twitter, lead

I'm exposing a web service to receive leads from [twitter /cards/lead_gen](https://dev.twitter.com/ads/reference/post/accounts/%3Aaccount_id/cards/lead_gen), the main problem it's I don't know what to expect (`submit_url` -> "HTTPS endpoint that will accept the leads"). I read the documentation but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Yes, the docs do not help (and Google shows me this question as the first result). Not the answer you're looking for, but you can always put an URL which logs all the requests with all the GET and POST fields. And probably they expect the request to return an HTTP error code, but I'm just guessing; they can also expect a json response from you.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is (i do not know why yet..) but when i try to configure a lead, does not works, never finish to upload the image that require to submit (test it on chrome and safari). Please, if works for you, can you paste some examples?